# Sample Size based on Variables Used

Tags: dataset, sample-size

I have survey data that collected responses for a number of variables.   I'm wondering, what are the best practices for dealing with missing data in this context?

To illustrate my question, consider this example:  Suppose I want to run two statistical tests on the survey data.

1. A chi-squared test between two categorical variables testing for independence;
2. A two sample t-test for a quantitative variable.

If I have missing responses in the raw data, how should I proceed?

For clarification, suppose that for only the chi-squared test variables there are 4 rows with missing data.  For only the t-test variables there are 6 rows with missing data.  If I consider all variables (both chi-squared and the t-test), there are 9 rows with missing data.

Here are some ideas:

a) remove the 4 rows and run the chi-squared test. Start again with all data, then remove the 6 rows and run the t-test;  or

b) remove the 9 rows where there is missing data for the variables of interest in *both tests*, and then do each statistical test?

What are the failings with these approaches, and what should one do instead?

I hope the question is clear, and thank you for any advice.

Comment: Could you tell us something about how many responses are missing, the pattern of missingness, and why you think they are missing?

Comment: @whuber, I think some people either didn't want to answer or missed a question. It's hard to say whether the missing data was intentional or just a mistake.  There were 104 total surveys, 100 have complete answers for the chi-squared test, 98 have complete answers for the t-test, and 95 have complete answers for both tests. I know these differences are not that much, but if the missing answers were more extreme, I'm wondering what the best practice would be.

Comment: That sounds like a good way to pose your question.  At present, that's not what you're asking: you are requesting that people help you choose between two alternative procedures that appear to ignore all issues of missingness, and therefore are of suspect value.

Comment: @whuber Yes, I'm not concerned with what to do with this particular data set. Rather, I'm more interested in general approaches and recommendations for working in situations like this.  I updated my question to be more general; hopefully the update makes more sense.

Comment: But now your post suffers even more greatly from how it is phrased.  It is in the form "Should I do X or Y" in a circumstance where procedures A, B, C, ..., W are called for--but rarely will X or Y be appropriate.

Comment: @whuber OK, I suppose my question is fundamentally what are the procedures A, B, C, ..., W which are called for, given that neither X nor Y are appropriate?

Comment: @whuber I revised the original question. Hopefully it's clearer.